# straight line detection in android

Tags: android

I have an image like:

[image]

And another image:

[image]

i have taken an image of a laser line.
My aim is to check if the image contains a straight line of the laser.If the image contains a straight line then give a message that "Straight line is found"  else "straight line is not found". I want to do that in android. I will input a image from SD card and output will be the message. My provided 1stimage should give message "Straight line is found"
 and 2nd image should give message "Straight line is not found" . I tried something like this but cant reach my goal:

```
         int iWidth2 = bmp.getWidth();  

           for(int i=0;i<bmp.getHeight();i++)
           {
               int found=0;

               for(int j=0;j<bmp.getWidth();j++)
               {

                   if(pixels[(i*iWidth2)+j]==Color.Red)
                   {
                       found++;
                   }

                }

                if(((found*100)/bmp.getWidth())>80)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Straight ",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

           }
```

As the laser color is not exactly red and that's why it doesn't give correct result.

Comment: Your code is based on Pin-Point-Accuracy! You are detecting A perfect- horizontally-aligned set of equal pixels. However you need to add a bit more flexibility to this algorithm, both in terms of color and selected scanning path. Or even better, you should not try to re-invent the wheel! Go for existing image scanning libraries if this is not just for fun.

Comment: You are using a Color constant, that's way too precise (See the actual value for RED here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/graphics/Color.java) Use a "red"ish-range in which found color has to be in.

Answer (score 1):

If background of your picture is always black, try to detect not black Color, but not unknown color of laser.

```
if(pixels[(i*iWidth2)+j]!=Color.Black)
{
  found++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line detection in images isn't that trivial as detecting single colored pixels. Because the line in your image has multiple colors and the stroke of the line can differ.

I would suggest to use a graphics library like OpenCV for this. There is also a [version for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

Have a look at [Hough Line Transformation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) and [Canny Edge Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html), which are processes to detect straight lines.